# Normal array declaration vs. dynamic array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

I just started learning C++. I learned the easy way of declaring arrays and now I'm confused about the usage of

```
int* foo = new int[n];
```

and how it is different from

```
int foo [n];
```

I tried testing with code but couldn't find any difference. I read from sources that using "new" requires me to manually de-allocate the memory after I don't need it anymore. In that case, there is no advantage in using "new" or dynamic memory allocation at all. Am I missing something here?

I tried running this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cout << "array size" ;

  std::cin >> n ;
  std::cout << n ;

  int foo [n]; //line A
  // int* foo = new int[n]; //line B
  foo[6] = 30;
  
  std::cout<<foo[6]<<std::endl;
}
```

Commenting out line B to run line A, or vice versa, gave the exact same result.

Comment: `int foo [n]` isn't valid c++ as `n` is not a compile-time constant

Comment: Only one of those is permitted by the C++ standard (the former). **V**ariable **L**ength **A**rrays are a compiler extension that doesn't work for all compilers. There are classes that take care of the memory (de)allocation for you such as `std::vector`. I recommend making use of this class since in addition to managing the memory for you it also comes with a bunch of other convenient functionality such as copying, resizing, insertion, ect...

Comment: `int foo [n];` is not Standard C++.  Some compilers will allow it as an extension but not all of them.  Therefore you should not use it except in very rare circumstances.   Please try and avoid c-arrays completely and use use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: what @fabian said plus the standard library has a whole lot of optimised algorithms that work with the interfaces of such containers

Comment: Also, `int* foo = new int[n];` does 3 things: 1) It creates a variable foo of type int*; 2) It creates a totally separate (unnamed) dynamic array of int; 3) It initializes the variable foo to point to the first element of the (unnamed) dynamic array. So your second option (besides not being part of the standard language) would do something different.

Comment: A common difficulty that people have first learning C++ is understanding the difference between a pointer and an array.  They are not the same thing!  `int* foo` is a pointer.  `int foo [n]` is an array.

Comment: *I just started learning C++.*  The `new` keyword is an advanced concept in modern C++, and should be learned once you've mastered the basics.  (After a couple years.)  Once you learn about `new`, in modern C++ you should not need to use it.  Instead you should rely on **smart pointers** (like `std::unique_ptr` via `std::make_unique`) and standard C++ library **containers** (like `std::vector`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways these are different. First, let's talk about this one:

```
int n = 10;
int array[n];
```

This is not part of the ANSI C++ standard and may not be supported by all compilers. You shouldn't count on it. Imagine this code:

```
int n = 10;
int array[n];
n = 20;
```

How big is `array`?

Now, this is the way you can do it (but it's still problematic):

```
int n = 10;
int * array = new int[n];
```

Now, that is legal. But you have to remember later to:

```
delete [] array;
array = nullptr;
```

Now, there are two other differences. The first one allocates space on the stack. The second allocates space on the heap, and it's persistent until you delete it (give it back). So the second one could return the array from a function, but the first one can't, as it disappears when the function exits.

HOWEVER... You are strongly, strongly discouraged from doing either. You should instead use a container class.

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, n> array;
```

The advantages of this:

1. It's standard and you can count on it
2. You don't have to remember to free it
3. It gives you range checking

Comment: OP's use case appears to be for run time sizing, which would be std::vector. std::array is only usable when the size can be determined at compile-time.